# PowerShell - Incrementing Left Hand Variable

Tags: powershell, foreach, import-csv

Attempting to import .csv cell contents into a PowerShell Form Combo/Drop Down Box which works when I hard code in each variable number ($DropDownBox1.Text,  $DropDownBox2.Text etc.) but was looking to make it a bit smarter and loop through each instance and import appropriately.

Is it possible to modify the left hand assignment to get it to increment accordingly?

```
$i=0
$x=1
Foreach($User in $ISDept)
{
    $DropDownBox[$x].Text = Import-Csv -Path $File | Select-object -Index ($i) |% {$_.Status}
    $i++
    $x++
}
```

Using the above code I get the error:

**"Unable to index into an object of type System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox."**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477933/478656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have some code that creates all dropdown boxes, with names as you described. In that case, you need to use dynamic variable and Get-Variable command. Try this

```
$i=0
$x=1
Foreach($User in $ISDept)
{
    $DropDownBox = Get-Variable -Name ('DropDownBox' + ([string]$x)) | Select -Expand Value
    $DropDownBox.Text = Import-Csv -Path $File | Select-object -Index ($i) |% {$_.Status}
    $i++
    $x++
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I had tried the get-variable function but my syntax when trying to join the 'DropDownBox' string and incrementing number was a bit off!?  Thanks again.